# Getting only 1 record from each category for each page in pagination

Tags: mysql

My table structure is as follows

```
id        int
name      varchar 50
catid     int
```

Sample data

```
id                     name                      catid
---------------------------------------------------------
 1                     AAA                         1
 2                     BBB                         1
 3                     CCC                         1
 4                     DDD                         2
 5                     EEE                         2
 6                     FFF                         1
 7                     GGG                         2
 8                     HHH                         2     
 9                     III                         1
```

**I want query such as it get me 1 row from each category for each page in pagination**

Now for 1st Page I need data as

```
id                     name                      catid
---------------------------------------------------------
 1                     AAA                         1
 4                     DDD                         2
```

Now for 2nd Page I need data as

```
id                     name                      catid
---------------------------------------------------------
 2                     BBB                         1
 5                     EEE                         2
```

Now for 3rd Page I need data as

```
id                     name                      catid
---------------------------------------------------------
 3                     CCC                         1
 7                     GGG                         2
```

and so on.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: Is it limited to category 1 and 2 for all pages or can this grow? I would think a union with a combination of limit might be the way to go.

Comment: @Rasika: yes, it's limited to category 1 and 2.

Comment: SELECT id, name, catid from t where catid=1 limit 2,1 union select id, name, catid from t where catid=2 limit 2,1

Comment: Above query didn't gave me 2 records, it just gave me single record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me (MySQL 5.1 on Linux)

```
SELECT id, name, catid FROM 
   (SELECT id, name, catid FROM t WHERE catid=1 LIMIT 2,1) AS t1 
   UNION (SELECT id, name, catid FROM t WHERE catid=2 LIMIT 2,1)
   ORDER BY catid
```

The 2 in the limit is the page number. Hence the output of this one is for the second page.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE catid = 1 LIMIT :pageno 1 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE catid = 2 LIMIT :pageno 1
```

I think, this will be simplest query to get required result.

Comment: It's not feasible to have query for each category. I need it in a single query, which can cover as many as catid in table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Pradeep said, a LIMIT clause would be the simplest way to do it in MySQL. You'll still need a little bit of coding in PHP to produce clickable page numbers for your users.